# How to a read camera video stream and store on FTP server using python

Tags: python, ftp, video-streaming, ip-camera, onvif

I'm new to onvif streaming using python.
I would like to read a video stream from a camera and directly store the video on my ftp server. I could come up with the following piece of code.

```
from ftplib import FTP
from io import BytesIO
import cv2

ftp = FTP('my-ftp-host-server')
ftp.login('my-ftp-user-id', 'my-ftp-password')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://camera-username:camera-password@192.168.2.122/1')

while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        flo = BytesIO(frame)
        ftp.storbinary('STOR video.mp4', flo)
    else:
        break

cap.release()
ftp.quit()
```

Unfortunately, when I download the stored video afterward, it is unreadable.

Could you please help me?

Comment: opencv is the **wrong library** for this. it decodes that video stream. you don't want that, you want to download the stream. use ffmpeg or gstreamer. -- why do you think turning a decoded frame into a BytesIO would be a valid video file? that's a single frame, not compressed, not wrapped in any video file format, ...

Comment: To be honest, I don't know the answers to your questions. As said, I'm absolutely new to the topic and I'm putting pieces of code from different sources/forums. I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: first mistake was to use OpenCV for this. it will decode the stream. now you'd have to recompress it. use a different library, OpenCV is for computer vision and that here isn't computer vision.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:
https://github.com/peterstamps/TAPO-camera-ONVIF-RTSP-and-AI-Object-Recognition-C-

Look in mycMotDetRec.cpp.

```cpp
// Convert the frame to JPEG format
vector<uchar> buffer;
//buffer for coding 
vector<int> param(2);
param[0] = cv::IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY; param[1] = 100; //default(95) 0-100 
cv::imencode(".jpg", frame, buffer, param);         
// Optional. Save the frame into a file
imwrite("./temp_frame.jpg", frame); 
// Optional. Load your image here.
Mat frame = imread("./temp_frame.jpg"); 

// make a image stream in bytes
stringstream image_stream;
for (const auto &byte : buffer) {
    image_stream << byte;
}
```

your reference to the data:

```
image_stream.str().c_str()
```

your reference to the data size:

```
buffer.size()
```

you can POST this for example with curl you use:

```
curl_mime_data(part, image_stream.str().c_str(), buffer.size())
```

Comment: I don't see any point in your answer. imwrite followed by imread is pointless. I'm sure that stringstreams support ways to get *the bytes in the buffer you already have* into the stream with a single operation, rather than running over the bytes in the buffer.

Comment: You  can comment these two lines.  I do not use them as well, but I kept them there and marked them optional. If you prefer a ftp from a file then you can use these lines. I POST direct from the buffer. You can go that way as well via ftp. So your observation is right. I was not clear about the intention of these two lines...

Comment: I was not clear about the intention of these two lines... But if you have a faster/shorter method, please post that here. This solution works for me.

Comment: all you showed is how to write an image file. OP's question deals with an entire stream and OP appears to ask for how to dump the received stream into a file, without transcoding of any kind.

Comment: You are right. I thought he wanted to ftp a picture from the buffer. I think he needs to write first to a file before he can use the ftp protocol. Ftp stands for file transfer protocol.The file must be closed before ftp can happen. He deals now with a stream. He can try to toggle between writing frames into file A and B, after x frames or x time switch to file B, close A and transfer A with FTP and so on. FTP of a stream is in my opinion not possible...

Comment: After checking with ChatGPT i got this answer.   CHatGPT says: Yes, it's possible to achieve continuous streaming without intermediate files using FTP. However, this would depend on the capabilities of both the camera and the FTP server software. Some cameras and FTP servers support streaming protocols like RTSP (Real-Time Streaming Protocol) or FTPS (FTP Secure) that allow for continuous streaming without creating intermediate files.

Comment: ChatgPT says(continue): You would need to configure the camera to stream directly to the FTP server using one of these protocols, and ensure that the FTP server is capable of handling and serving the continuous stream. Additionally, you may need to consider network bandwidth and server resources to ensure smooth and uninterrupted streaming.

Comment: ChatGPT can't help you here.